# Passing a password issues

Tags: powershell

Hoping someone can maybe offer some insight or solution. Working with the powershell module PowerCommander for Keeper security. We have MFA via SSO for login to Keeper. I want to begin looking into automation of some tasks for scripts etc.

So we can pass the account password fine it's the master password we cannot pass as a parameter it needs to be entered each time. Below is an example, it takes the `-Password` fine. `-SSOPassword` it would prompt for master password, enter this fine and it connects. If i put in similar code to define this master password it errors saying the parameter cannot be found. So looks like it doesn't allow it..

```
$Password = "PASSWORD Here"
$Pass = ($Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force)

Connect-Keeper -Username User@Test.com -Password $Pass -SsoPassword
```

Aware putting password in is not best practice but for ease of testing i wanted to be quick on that part.

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message, and what is the code you used to define the password? It sounds like the error is either because one of your inputs is null, or you cannot use two of the parameters together. Just to make sure, `Get-Help Connect-Keeper`, powershell will list the valid parameter set(s) and the type of input they expect under `SYNTAX`.

Comment: You can't use Password.  You must create a credential which encrypts the password.  Most windows systems will block an unencrypted password.  See https://pscustomobject.github.io/powershell/howto/PowerShell-Create-Credential-Object/

Comment: @Cpt.Whale so the error i get is 'A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument' seems like you cannot pass a paramter into using a variable. So i want to knwo if there is another way to pass this master password.

`  -SsoPassword [<SwitchParameter>]
        Use Master Password for SSO account
        
        Required?                    false
        Position?                    named
        Default value                False
        Accept pipeline input?       false
        Accept wildcard characters?  false `

Comment: @Kevlar The code you've posted above has 0 positional arguments being passed to `Connect-Keeper`, so that's a bit surprising. Can you post the error message in full? [Please add it to your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78200843/edit)

Comment: If you look inside the [source code for the module](https://github.com/Keeper-Security/keeper-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/PowerCommander/AuthCommands.ps1), you will find function `Connect-Keeper` in \PowerCommander\AuthCommands starting at line 316.
Inspect the parameters that function can take and you'll see that parameter `SsoPassword` is a **switch**; not a string or SecureString like the `Password` parameter. You can either add it to the command or leave it out, but you cannot use it to provide the master password.

Comment: @Kevlar Like Mathias says, the example command in your question does not contain the positional parameters it's complaining about. This makes me think either you are running the command differently, or the error is coming from elsewhere in the module. The rest of the error message text should help clear that up if you can add the whole thing to your question

Comment: It looks like the module doesn't allow it to be passed which we found in the code as per one of the comments above. We have submitted to the vendor if they can change it so you can. If we edit the module code we could pass it.. Not ideal when they update the module everyone has to then update the code.

Comment: @Kevlar ah okay, I think I misread the question since your example does not attempt to pass anything to `-SsoPassword`.